# is it possible to build android apps on windows server 2012?

Tags: android, windows, windows-server-2012

i want to create a build service for android apps, however windows 8 takes too many resources to have it as a server, so is it possible to install android SDKs en build apps on windows server?

Thanks

Comment: What is `a build service for android apps`?

Comment: what i mean in general is the ability to compile android apps like in eclipse etc

Comment: OK. But what kind of special server do you want to use that windows 8 is not able to handle? XP can already run all web services.

Comment: its not about thar Windows 8 doesnt handle it.. i just want to setup a server where i can do android builds.. the only thing i need to know if i can do it on a Windows server too

Comment: If you can install Word on it or FireFox then I would say yes.

Comment: I thought it had some limitations because it was a server, but if that is possible, it will work i guess.. will try soon and post an answer. Thanks ;)

Comment: @CaptainObvious how did you go with Android dev on win2012? Any difficulties?

Comment: it worked fine :)